# Navigation buttons are showing off to the side of react-image-gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-image-gallery](https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery) and would like the navigation buttons (left, right, play, full screen) to show on the image itself, as shown in the demo. However, in my case, they are showing off to the side:
[image]

Here is the code I'm running:

```js
import ImageGallery from "react-image-gallery";
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

const imgHeight = '500px';
const images = [
    {
        original: '/homePageImages/img1.jpeg',
        originalHeight: imgHeight,
    },
    {
        original: '/homePageImages/img2.jpeg',
        originalHeight: imgHeight,
    },
    {
        original: '/homePageImages/img3.jpeg',
        originalHeight: imgHeight,
    },
    {
        original: '/homePageImages/img4.jpeg',
        originalHeight: imgHeight,
    },
]

const HomePage = () => (
    <div>
        <ImageGallery items={images} />
    </div>
);
```

Looking at the list of props, nothing seems like it would fix this. Thank you in advance!